# What are the specifications of the BXT-36R battery?

Tags: battery

I am trying to figure out how many CCA a replacement battery for my 97 Ford Taurus should have by looking at the [Motorcraft battery BXT-36R](http://www.fordparts.com/Commerce/PartDetail.aspx?n=Te8yb6x3rZs6mt2f1Ck9zw%3D%3D&id=391476216&m=44&search=true&year=1997&make=Ford&model=Taurus) recommended in the [manual](http://justgivemethedamnmanual.com/ford/1997-ford-taurus-owners-manual). But I can't seem to find the specs for it. Googling did not help.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are CA at 32 degrees F:800
                   CCA at 0 degrees F:650

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for posting! This looks about right. Do you have a reference for it? Might help others in the future with similar questions if there's more information than what you have posted.

Comment: And here is a reference (does give a warning about specs can change...):
http://machenry.com/documents/batteryspecs.pdf